# Question about BigQuery mismatch the GA4 UI data

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I've been trying to figure out why GA4 has different session volume compares with UA data, right now, by using Mar 21st 2023 as an example,
[there are 104 Sessions in UA,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDcLf.png) 
and
[there are 331 session in GA4.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IblCa.png)

I tried to understand GA4 session volume by using BigQuery. Here i tried to methodologies from online source, and they were all off from actual 331 session in GA4.

Here are the queries i tried

`count(distinct concat(user_pseudo_id,(select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'ga_session_id'))) as sessions, count(distinct concat(user_id,(select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'ga_session_id'))) as sessions`

The first one came out result as 175, and the second one came out result as 278.

Does anyone know what might be the reason for this?

Comment: https://sqlformat.org/ might help with the readability of your two queries

Answer (score 0):

In your first query you look at the count of unique combinations of `user_pseudo_id` (= a random ID GA generates and usually stores in a cookie) with `ga_session_id`.

In your second query you look at the count of unique combinations of `user_id` (= an identifier you provide yourself, e.g. a customer ID) with `ga_session_id`.

So the difference between the two really depends on how you have implemented `user_id` in the website/app tracking.